# Solving Linear Recursion with backtracking

Tags: recurrence-relations

What am I doing wrong? Is there a missing step?

Tried googling but cannot seem to get it.

Question: 
$$\begin{align}
a_{n} &= a_{n-1}+2n+3 ,\\ 
a_{0} &= 4
\end{align}$$

Things I did:

$$\begin{align}
a_{n}&=a_{n-1}+2n+3\\
&= (a_{n-2}-2n+3) +2n+3\\
&= (a_{n-3}-2n+3) + 2(2n) + 3(3)\\
&...\\
&...\\
\end{align}$$

Then I got:

$$\begin{align}
a_n &= 2n^2 + 3n + 4
\end{align}$$

Comment: Notice that when you are backtracking, the $n$ on the $2$ should be changing with the subscipt of $a$. So the second line should read $(a_{n-2} - 2(n-1) +3) + 2n+3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are attempting:

$$\begin{align}
a_n &= a_{n-1} + 2n + 3 
\\  &= (a_{n-2} + 2(n-1) + 3) + 2n + 3  &&= a_{n-2} + (2 + 2)n + 3 + 3 - 2
\\  &= (a_{n-3} + 2(n-2) + 3) + (2 + 2)n + 3 + 3 - 2
   &&= a_{n-3} + (2\cdot 3)n + 3\cdot 3 -  2 - 4 
\\  &= (a_{n-4} + 2(n-3) + 3) + (2\cdot 3)n + 3\cdot 3 -  2 - 4 
   &&= a_{n-4} + (2\cdot 4)n + 3\cdot 4 -  2 - 4 - 6
\\  &= (a_{n-5} + 2(n-4) + 3) + (2\cdot 4)n + 3\cdot 4 -  2 - 4 - 6
   &&= a_{n-5} + (2\cdot 5)n + 3\cdot 5 -  2 - 4 - 6 - 8
\\ &= \dots &&= \dots
\end{align}$$

Can you see the pattern yet?  $a_n = a_{n-k} + \text{something}$

Use the observation from "backtracking" to guess what that $\text{something}$ is.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{a_{0}\ =\ 4}$. With $\ds{\verts{z}\ <\ 1}$:

\begin{align}
{\cal F}\pars{z}&\equiv\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}a_{n - 1}z^{n} + 2\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}nz^{n}
+ 3\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}z^{n}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n + 1} + {2z \over \pars{1 - z}^{2}}
+ {3z \over 1 - z}
=z\bracks{a_{0} + {\cal F}\pars{z}} + {2z \over \pars{1 - z}^{2}}
+ {3z \over 1 - z}
\\[5mm]\imp\ \pars{1 - z}{\cal F}\pars{z}&=
4z + {2z \over \pars{1 - z}^{2}} + {3z \over 1 - z}
\\[5mm]\imp\ {\cal F}\pars{z}&={4z \over 1 - z} + {2z \over \pars{1 - z}^{3}} + {3z \over \pars{1 - z}^{2}}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}4z^{n}+
3\sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}n\pars{n - 1}z^{n - 1} + 3\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}nz^{n}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}4z^{n}+
3\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\pars{n + 1}nz^{n} + 3\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}nz^{n}
\\[4mm]&=4 + 9z + \sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}\bracks{4 + \pars{n + 1}n + 3n}z^{n}
\end{align}

> Then,
>   $$\color{#66f}{\large%
> a_{0}=4\,,\quad a_{1}=9\,,\quad a_{n}=4 + \pars{n + 1}n + 3n
> =n^{2} + 4n + 4\,,\ n \geq 2}
> $$

Comment: I believe the asker is attempting to learn how to use substitution to mechanically guess what nonrecursive representation of a recursive formula would be.  Generating functions seems like overkill for a student who is even trying to use google for help, doesn't it seem almost dismissive to post an answer like this for this level of a question?

Comment: @DanielV I understand and I'm agree with your point of view. However, the OP can keep this answer for his/her record in the near future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+2n+3$$
$$a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}+2(n-1)+3$$
$$......$$
$$a_1=a_0+2\cdot1+3$$
adding both sides respectively yields
$$a_n+(a_{n-1}+...+a_1)=(a_{n-1}+...+a_1)+a_0+2\cdot(n+(n-1)+...+1)+3\cdot n$$
$$a_n=a_0+2\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+3\cdot n=4+n^2+4n$$
for all $n\geq0$.